# Why does my while loop end without giving an error? C++

Tags: c++, windows, while-loop, named-pipes

I have a project which you can create named pipes in c# or c++ and this program will work as a middle man and simply pass the data on. Used to maintain integrity. Though in one of my while loops when I debug it I step on the while loop then it will cancel the steps and not process the while loop. It reaches line 107 of this code. If you need more of my files I will be happy to post them if needed.

```
//Information\\
//----------------------------------------\\

//File Name: NamedPipes.cpp
//Date Of Creation: 03/12/2019
//Purpose
/*
This file is to handle the interprocess communication
between the pipes.
*/

//----------------------------------------\\

//Internal Includes\\
//----------------------------------------\\

#include "NamedPipes.h"
#include "MiddleMan.h"

//----------------------------------------\\

//Global Variables\\
//----------------------------------------\\

struct Connection NamedPipes::Server;
struct Connection NamedPipes::Client;

//----------------------------------------\\

//Functions\\
//----------------------------------------\\

int NamedPipes::CreateServer()
{
    try
    {
        LPTSTR lpszPipename = (LPTSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\Omni3";
        LPTSTR lpszPipename2 = (LPTSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\Omni4";
        while (1) {
            Server.Write = CreateNamedPipe(lpszPipename, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024 * 16, 1024 * 16, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, NULL);
            Server.Read = CreateNamedPipe(lpszPipename2, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024 * 16, 1024 * 16, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, NULL);
            if (Server.Write == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (ConnectNamedPipe(Server.Write, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
            {
                Server.Connected = true;
                DWORD  dwThreadId = 0;
                HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
                    NULL,              // no security attribute 
                    0,                 // default stack size 
                    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MiddleMan::Pass,    // thread proc
                    (LPVOID)&Server,    // thread parameter
                    0,                 // not suspended 
                    &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID 
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}

int NamedPipes::CreateClient()
{
    try
    {
        DWORD last_error;
        unsigned int elapsed_seconds = 0;
        const unsigned int timeout_seconds = 5;
        LPTSTR lpszPipename = (LPTSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\Omni1";
        LPTSTR lpszPipename2 = (LPTSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\Omni2";
        Client.Read = CreateFile(lpszPipename, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
        Client.Write = CreateFile(lpszPipename2, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
        while (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == Client.Read &&
            elapsed_seconds < timeout_seconds)
        {
            last_error = GetLastError();

            if (last_error != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
            {
                break;
            }

            Sleep(1000);
            elapsed_seconds++;

            Client.Read = CreateFile(lpszPipename, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
            Client.Write = CreateFile(lpszPipename2, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
        }

        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == Client.Read)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to connect to pipe " << lpszPipename <<
                ": last_error=" << last_error << "\n";
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Connected to pipe " << lpszPipename << "\n";
        }
        DWORD  dwThreadId = 0;
        Client.Connected = true;
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
            NULL,              // no security attribute 
            0,                 // default stack size 
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MiddleMan::Pass,    // thread proc
            (LPVOID)&Client,    // thread parameter 
            0,                 // not suspended 
            &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID 
        return 1;
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}


/*
This function will loop until it recieves a transmission from the external UI.
*/
string NamedPipes::RecieveInformation(HANDLE Pipe)
{
    BOOL fSuccess;
    char chBuf[2048];
    DWORD cbRead;
    int i;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Pipe) {
                fSuccess = ReadFile(Pipe, chBuf, 2048, &cbRead, NULL);
                if (cbRead != NULL && fSuccess)
                {
                    string s(chBuf);
                    s.resize(cbRead);
                    printf("Pipe Recieved: %s\n", s.c_str());
                    return s;
                }
                printf("Error: Couldn't Read Pipe\n");
                Sleep(500);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error: Invalid Pipe\n");
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        printf("Error Unknown\n");
    }
}

int NamedPipes::SendInformation(HANDLE Pipe, string Information)
{
    char buf[2048];
    DWORD cbWritten;
    try
    {
        strcpy(buf, Information.c_str());
        if (!WriteFile(Pipe, buf, (DWORD)strlen(buf), &cbWritten, NULL))
        {
            printf("Message Sending Failed. Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
    }
    return 1;
}

//----------------------------------------\\
```

EDIT: If it helps this is MiddleMan::Pass

```
void MiddleMan::Pass(LPVOID Pipe2)
{
    Connection Pipe = *(Connection *)Pipe2;
    while (1)
    {
        string Information = NamedPipes::RecieveInformation(Pipe.Read);
        if (Information != "") {
            if (Pipe.Read == NamedPipes::Server.Read)
            {
                if (NamedPipes::Client.Connected) {
                    NamedPipes::SendInformation(NamedPipes::Client.Write, Information);
                }
            }
            else if (Pipe.Read == NamedPipes::Client.Read)
            {
                if (NamedPipes::Server.Connected) {
                    NamedPipes::SendInformation(NamedPipes::Server.Write, Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice it doesn't say the line numbers so. In RecieveInformation function. on the line ReadFile. That's when it just stops with no error messages.

Comment: When you say stops, do you mean the program exits or it just hangs there?

Comment: @Borgleader The program continues but I can no longer track it with the debugger. Meaning I assume there is an error of some sorts, but I have no idea how to know what the error is.

Comment: That's normal behavior in multithreaded applications ; check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multithreaded-applications-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 . I suggest running your code in main thread first to locate the problem.

Comment: @Ziri It was a great idea and I have just now attempted this. When it reached that line it once again stopped. So I'm still none the wiser.

Comment: If I set a breakpoint on if (cbRead != NULL && fSuccess) It never reaches the line